# Adding letsencrypt cert broke nginx config

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I have Nginx, running on Ubuntu 16.04 with several virtual hosts set up.
After adding a LetsEncrypt cert, using certbot, I can no longer access my site with www.example.com Going to example.com works perfectly with either protocol. If I go to www.example.com with either protocol, the server returns the default server block. 
Here is my server block in the Nginx configuration files:

```
server {

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    root /var/www/example/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

     location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
server {
listen 80;

server_name example.com www.example.com;
return 302 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

I want the server to respond to https://www.example.com OR http://www.example.com the same way it currently responds to https://example.com

Comment: Does it work with `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com`? What do you want to happen? Different sites with `www.` and without `www.`? Or all sites redirected to `www.`?

Comment: https://example.com works. http://example.com redirects to https://example.com. www.example.com does not work with either protocol. I edited the post to try and clarify.

Comment: What is your "default server block"? We can't see everything in your config. Edit: alright, you added an answer. One question: do you really _want_ to use HTTP 302? Better fitting would be 301.

Comment: I don't allow certbot to write nginx configs. I do that myself (with configuration management). Not to mention that it frequently seems to screw up. Consider doing the same.

Comment: @Lenniey I used 302 temporarily so I didn't have to deal with browser cache while I was testing. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the answer to help others who may end up in the same sitch.

Be sure to check all virtual hosts files. In my case Certbot had written a server block for the www version of my site within the digitalocean virtual host file. I deleted that server block and the code above worked as expected.

You can test your configuration to find if you have the same problem by doing the following:

- run `sudo nginx -t`
- if the above returns something about a conflicting server name, look for the duplicate server block

I hope this helps